# Foreach is showing only one result instead of all

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to select elements from only one category and show them on page. 
Currently I have 5 posts in this category but on page I see only one.

Why is that?

Here is how I try

```
<?php
$args = array(   
    'showposts'=>-1,
    'category_name' => 'custom-page',
); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$aSolutionsePost = array();
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $aSolutionsePost = array();
            $query->the_post();
            $aSolutionsePost['title'] = $query->post->post_title;
            $aSolutionsePost['content'] = $query->post->post_content;
        }
}
?>

<div class="col-4 ">
    <ul class="price">
    <?php if(!empty($aSolutionsePost)){?>

        <?php foreach($aSolutionsePost as $item){ ?>
        <li class="header"><?php echo $item->title; ?></li>
        <li class="grey"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$item->content);?></li>
        <?php }?>               
    <?php }?>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I `print_r($aSolutionsePost);` I see only one result. This:

```
Array ( 
      [title] => Price test title 
      [content] => Price test content 

      [0] => Array ( 
             [title] => Price test title 
             [content] => Price test content 
      ) 
)
```

Comment: I fail to understand the purpose of `$aSolutionsePost[] = $aSolutionsePost;`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove it. I've been tried different codes from other threads. Will remove it now.

Comment: Everytime you loop, you re-init the array `$aSolutionsePost` -> your array either empty or have the last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code inside your `while ( $query->have_posts() )` loop:

```
$aSolutionsePost = array();
```

is overwriting the value of `$aSolutionsePost` each pass through the loop. You probably want something like this instead:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $aSolutionsePost[] = array('title' => $query->post->post_title,
                               'content' => $query->post->post_content);
}
```

Note that in your code to echo the results, you are treating the array elements as objects, not associative arrays. It's simplest to just change those lines to this:

```
<li class="header"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></li>
<li class="grey"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$item['content']);?></li>
```

but if you want to keep that code the same you can change the assignment line to this:

```
$aSolutionsePost[] = (object)array('title' => $query->post->post_title,
                                   'content' => $query->post->post_content);
```

Comment: Yes, I've managed to fix this and that's why I've delete the comment. How can I sort the results from first to last because currently they are from last to first. I've tried to `asort($aSolutionsePost);` before the while .. but that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `first` to `last`?

Comment: First post in that category till Last post. Now is showing Last post as first.

Comment: The code will echo the posts in the order they come out from the query. So perhaps you need to add ordering to the query? e.g. by date descending?

Comment: Okay, enough for today. It's so obvious that I need to order by the query not try to sort the array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check array set inside while,

You re-create `$aSolutionsePost` every time, so it will be reseted.
Solution is to create new array and append it to `$aSolutionsePost`, check below snippet.

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $tmpSolutionsePost = array();
    $query->the_post();
    $tmpSolutionsePost['title'] = $query->post->post_title;
    $tmpSolutionsePost['content'] = $query->post->post_content;
    $aSolutionsePost[] = $tmpSolutionsePost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  actually updating the same array with new values in the loop.

```
$finalData =array(); 
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $aSolutionsePost = array();
            $query->the_post();
            $aSolutionsePost['title'] = $query->post->post_title;
            $aSolutionsePost['content'] = $query->post->post_content;
            $finalData[] = $aSolutionsePost;
        }
```

Now iterate over `$finalData`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding the element to same key of array again and again and that is why there is only 1 element in the array, hence foreach is showing only 1 element.
You should possibly take 2d array to solve this purpose.